# Don't understand this Invalid argument error

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\한찬희\Desktop\졸업작품\indexer_test1.py", line 191, in 
<module>
    with open('./searchJson2.json/') as data_file:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: './searchJson2.json/
```

[image: Folder contents screenshot]

[image: code screenshot]

Comment: Filenames don't end with slashes. Does `open('./searchJson2.json')` work?

Comment: I fixed it ... and there was an error.
I fixed it ... and there was an error.
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\한찬희\Desktop\졸업작품\indexer_test1.py", line 192, in <module>
    search_list = json.loads(data_file.read())
  File "C:\Users\한찬희\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)

Comment: Post your code as plain text, not an image.

Comment: File "C:\Users\한찬희\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\한찬희\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: You get that last error if json tries to decode an empty string. Is the file empty?

Comment: yes. .json is the file empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the path is not correct. Remove the trailing slash.

It should be:

> with open('./searchJson2.json') as data_file:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\한찬희\Desktop\졸업작품\indexer_test1.py", line 192, in <module>
    search_list = json.loads(data_file.read())
  File "C:\Users\한찬희\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)

Comment: File "C:\Users\한찬희\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\한찬희\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: @한찬희 Sounds like the file doesn't contain valid JSON.

Comment: The answer respond to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
with open('{0}/searchJson2.json'.format(dir_path),'r+') as data_file:
```